# size column to longest cell with flexbox as if a grid

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have the following rows of a table that I'm trying to build using flexbox without a table element or css grid and was first able to solve a problem with cells with large amounts of text to not wrap the text, which strangely enough involves disabling flex grow and shrink, although the cells need to grow or shrink to accommodate the contents.  But in doing so, I ran into the problem of the cells being resized to fit the content exactly when I'd like for the cell of a column to be sized to the longest cell of the column it belongs to.  The code I have is as follows:

```css
.row {
  display: flex;
}

.row > div {
  border: solid;
  flex: 0 0 auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
  <div class="row">
    <div>
      joe smith
    </div>
    <div>
      100 Broadway st. New York City, New York
    </div>
    <div>
      100 Broadway st. New York City, New York
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div>
      100 Broadway st. New York City, New York 100 Broadway st. New York City, New York
    </div>
    <div>
      joe smith
    </div>
    <div>
      100 Broadway st. New York City, New York
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

A viewable example can be found here: https://jsfiddle.net/pefm968u/3

Comment: Please look at: [how to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: you can't do that with flexboxes, you need tables or grid

Comment: Why not use a table if your data is tabular?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you're assuming a flex container in row-direction has columns. It doesn't. There is even less association between the items of two different flex containers, like in your layout.

If you need the appearance of columns, then set a fixed width on the items. Otherwise, tables and Grid are the way to go.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want to use inline-block styled elements, not flexbox:

```
.row {
  display: inline-block;
}

.row > div {
  border: solid;
}
```

Alternatively you could keep the flexbox, but you will lose your columns:

```
* {
  display: inline-block;
}

.row {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.row > div {
  border: solid;
}
```